# Python3 Control flow statement elif does not allow for work above it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So recently I've been doing some Leetcode and I was writing my solution. I have a snippet like so

```
  def vowel_spellcheck(query):
        query_lower = query.lower()
        query_devoweled = devoweled(query.lower())
        if query in word_ref: 
            return query
    
        
        elif query_lower in word_lower:
            return word_lower[query_lower]
        
        elif query_devoweled in word_vowel:
            return word_vowel[query_devoweled]
        
        return ""
```

which is fine. However when I try to do

```
  def vowel_spellcheck(query):
        query_lower = query.lower()
        query_devoweled = devoweled(query.lower())
        if query in word_ref: 
            return query
    
        print("doing some work")
        elif query_lower in word_lower:
            return word_lower[query_lower]
        
        elif query_devoweled in word_vowel:
            return word_vowel[query_devoweled]
        
        return ""
```

The compiler complains. I've tried looking across as to the reasoning as to why this is not allowed. Are other languages like this as well?

Comment: The `print` above your first `elif` is outdented. It ends the `if` block. Indent the `print` into the `if` block.

Comment: let's say I wanted to do the print statement after the if statement so in order to not have the indent close for the if statement I should intialize it before the if statement then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a programming language that has *if/else* statements and *doesn't* work this way. `if/elif/else` is generally a semantic unit and the `elif/else` continuation clauses are subordinate to the `if`. Allowing unconditional execution between clauses could generally make associating an `else` with a any of a number of previous `if`'s a challenge.

In python in particular, dedenting closes the suite of statements under the `if`. If the next token is not an "elif" or "else", the entire `if` statement is concluded. "elif" and "else" are not allowed to start a new statement, so are syntax errors. See [Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements).

In this example every conditional returns, so `elif` is not needed.

```
def vowel_spellcheck(query):
    query_lower = query.lower()
    query_devoweled = devoweled(query.lower())

    if query in word_ref: 
        return query

    print("doing some work")

    if query_lower in word_lower:
        return word_lower[query_lower]
    
    if query_devoweled in word_vowel:
        return word_vowel[query_devoweled]
    
    return ""
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, unindent causes the if statement to stop. so just use multiple if statements.
"elif" and "else" are not allowed to start a new statement, so are syntax error.
You added return to every statement then it returns and stop the function. so you don't need to do extra `elif`:

```
def vowel_spellcheck(query):
        query_lower = query.lower()
        query_devoweled = devoweled(query.lower())
        if query in word_ref: 
            return query
    
        print("doing some work")
        if query_lower in word_lower:
            return word_lower[query_lower]
        
        if query_devoweled in word_vowel:
            return word_vowel[query_devoweled]
        
        return ""
```